# How to add some text at every x or nth line ending

Tags: notepad++

I want to add ; at every second line of my notepad file.
I just get the solution for adding at the beginning but not at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use Macro Recording

1. Make sure that Word Wrap option is off.
2. Move the cursor the line being added the trailing ;
3. Click on the "Start Recording" button on the tool bar
4. Hit the key End
5. Hit the key ;
6. Hit the key Right Arrow. You move to the the next line
7. Hit the key Down Arrow. You move to the next line
8. Click on the "Stop Recording" button. It's ready to use now.
9. Go to the next line needing the trailing ;
10. Click on the Run a Macro Multiple Times...
11. Select Run Until the end of file. Click Run.

If you need to skip every nth line, repeat step 6 for n-1 times.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\R.+$`
- Replace with: `$0;`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  .+        : 1 or more any character but new line
  \R        : any kind of linebreak
  .+        : 1 or more any character but new line
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          : content of group 0 (ie the whole match: 2 lines)
;           : a semi-colon
```

With file like:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

it gives:

```
abc
def;
ghi
jkl;
```